# Failed to display value service in Angular

Tags: angular, multidimensional-array, angular-ui-router, rxjs, angular-services

I am trying to display service containing country code and details but I am  getting error in console I am putting all the details below

**Error**

> localhost/:1 Failed to load http://country.io/names.json: No
>   'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested
>   resource. Origin 'http://localhost:4200' is therefore not allowed
>   access.

**countrycode.service.ts**

```
import { Http } from '@angular/http';
import {Injectable} from '@angular/core';
import { map } from 'rxjs/operators';
@Injectable()
export class CodeCountryService {

  constructor(private http: Http) { }

  getData() {
    return this.http.get('http://country.io/names.json').pipe(map(
     (response) => response.json()
    )).subscribe(

        (data) => console.log(data)

       );

  }
}
```

**code-country.ts**

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { CodeCountryService } from '../services/Contrycode.service';



@Component({
  selector: 'app-code-country',
  templateUrl: './code-country.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./code-country.component.css']
})
export class CodeCountryComponent implements OnInit {

  constructor(private _CodeCountryService: CodeCountryService) { }

  getData() {


  }

  ngOnInit() {
    this._CodeCountryService.getData();
  }

}
```

Comment: It's due as you are making a request on a non secure server ('http'). There is probably some solution that I don't know. You can disable CORS if you use it on the server side, but I think that even that Angular will block you. You can probably use a proxy to make those kind of request.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error message tells you all you need to know really. You're trying to do a request to a different domain, known as a Cross Domain Request, or CORS. If you'd like to understand what CORS is, why it exists, and what it does... I'd highly advice you to read:
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/CORS

Assuming you have no server access, and really want to use this resource, you'll need to proxy it. For your dev server in Angular using the CLI webpack-proxy is supported. You use it by kicking off your program using `ng serve --proxy-config ./proxy.conf.json`. You see there's a redirect to a proxy config file here, you can add your proxy config there. It looks like this:

```
{
   "/country": {
      "target": "http://country.io/",
      "secure": false,
      "changeOrigin": true
   },
}
```

Then your get request would request the local alias, as such:

```
getData() {
    return this.http.get('country/names.json').pipe(map(
     (response) => response.json()
    )).subscribe(

        (data) => console.log(data)

       );

  }
```